# Dealing with the "StanfordTokenizer will be deprecated in version 3.2.5" Warning

Tags: python, nltk, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I was testing the StanfordNERTagger using the NLTK wrapper and this warning appeared:

```
DeprecationWarning: The StanfordTokenizer will be deprecated in version 
3.2.5. Please use nltk.tag.corenlp.CoreNLPPOSTagger or 
nltk.tag.corenlp.CoreNLPNERTagger instead.
super(StanfordNERTagger, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

My code looks like this:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, ne_chunk
from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger

sentence = "Today George went to school and met his friend Peter."

# stanford's NER tagger 3 entity classification
st = StanfordNERTagger('/home/hercules/Desktop/PhD/Tools/stanford-ner-
     2017-06-09/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz',
     '/home/hercules/Desktop/PhD/Tools/stanford-ner-2017-06-09/stanford-
     ner.jar',
     encoding='utf-8')

tokenized_text = word_tokenize(sentence)
classified_text = st.tag(tokenized_text)

print("Stanford NER tagger:")
print(classified_text)
```

I tried to use CoreNLPNERTagger but I could not find any examples or documentation. 
I only found this [link:](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tag/stanford.html)
where it gives something like an example in the comments of the 
class CoreNLPNERTagger(CoreNLPTagger)                                      (I found it by searching the keyword "CoreNLPNERTagger")

I tried to follow that example with no use.
I think I should start (if that is the correct term) the coreNLP server first but if is that the case I don't know how.

If anyone got any idea or advice I would be grateful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was cross posted

Comment: I don't get why cross posting makes a question off topic.
And given that the question has 1k views shows that a lot of people had the same issue with me and searched SO.

Comment: Cross posting a question makes it eligible for deletion actually. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). Usually we delete it, but given that this has a lot of views and a partially good answer, I decided not to delete it and just close it.

Comment: The link you provide does not justify that. Check Faheem Mitha's commend on the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to follow rules which have been created as answers on Meta. If you feel that cross posting should be allowed, feel free to create a new post on http://meta.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the actual rule then?

Comment: That answer posted there is the actual rule. Cross posting is not allowed on Stack Exchange sites and we are expected to delete posts which are cross posted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177227/discussion-between-imoutidi-and-bhargav-rao).

Answer (score 1):

Well i found myself working with Stanford POS Tagger recently (got a similar warning) but still the tagger is still working.
The thing is, this is a warning telling you that they will change/remove the StanfordNERTagger class (more information about the [warning](http://www.lesinskis.com/python_deprecation_tutorial.html)).
What i advise you to do is to maintain your code with [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) or just copy the module (that's what i did) for example in order to keep your nltk module the way it is (avoid updating therefore sticking with this class).
Hope this helps you.